# Voltage Multiplier from Flash Camera Components

Tags: capacitor, high-voltage

I have a bunch of Flash Camera capacitors and charging boards. I'm hoping to make some fun little projects with them. I couldn't figure out how to run a CRT flyback after getting it out of the tv so this should be some easier High Voltage "*SAFE*" fun.

I'm looking for ideas of what do do with them? Could I put all the charging boards in series for some high voltage or could I put the caps in series to do the same? I have 3 CRT TVs worth of parts and access to the internet so any cheap (less than $100) project ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I think [this meta topic](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/3007/2028) applies here.

Comment: I still got what I wanted from the question :P I probably should have used some form of chat though; I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

[Battery-powered portable CFL lantern.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4Qo68HvxoE) It is possible to take the voltage multiplier from a flash camera and with a few tweaks light a bare CFL tube with it using only a single AA.

Comment: I've never been able to get the thing apart with the bulb intact but it's worth trying again :P

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not really fun, but making an ESD gun might be useful for testing comms links, and general susceptibility of electronic circuits ie proving their robustness. It doesn't have to meet any particular standards just be able to crack over a few kilovolts via a current limit resistor. It would be cool but maybe not fun!

Might be some money to be made as well. Hiring a simple battery device for local companies who are too tight to pay the full hire cost of a proper gun.

Comment: Neat idea! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the caps along with some magnet wire and make a coil gun (Rail gun).

Or for the less ballisticly inclined, use the caps to make a spot welder.

Comment: I tried the coil gun but couldn't get it to work. I used 1 or more of the flash camera caps. I made a decent coil, I think, but it didn't work.